# Function Return paths

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, return

I've got the following code and I really don't like the 'return string.Empty;' at the end but it's the only way I can keep Visual Studio from barking at me.

Can someone give me some advice on avoiding this?  Or when or how to use 'using'

Also are there good resources on TDD?  I can't figure out how to write tests for this.

```
private string GetWMIProperty(string property)
{
    SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
    {
         string value = string.Empty;
         foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
         {
              return mo[property].ToString();
         }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong in string.empty ? Why you did not like it ?

Comment: Those are three very different topics: `using` statements, TDD and code paths. Pick one, and create 2 others questions for the remaining topics.

Comment: Why are you returning within a `foreach`? That will just return the first item.

Comment: Hint: Regarding your TDD question, you shouldn't ask for off-site resources on stack overflow. You should come up with a specific problem and ask about that.

Comment: `using` has nothing to do with the VS complaints. The problem is that if `Get()` returns empty collection nothing will be returned from the method, which is not correct. Also are you aware of the fact that if `Get` return more than one item - only first will be returned?

Comment: @Andrei: Agreed, I removed `using` from the question. It isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you are returning from the foreach loop so that it returns only first item.

**Solution 1:** if you are sure that you have only one item that willbe returned from foreach loop then you can save that in a string variable and return at the end.

Try This:

```
private string GetWMIProperty(string property)
{
 string value = string.Empty;
 SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
 using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
 {

   foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
   {
     value = mo[property].ToString();
   }
 }
return value;
}
```

**Solution 2:** if your foreach loop can iterate for more than 1 time then its better to save your items into some Collection and then return that Collection instead of string

Try This:

```
private List<string> GetWMIProperty(string property)
{
 List<string> value =new  List<string>();
 SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
 using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
 {

   foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
   {
     value.Add(mo[property].ToString());
   }
 }
return value;
}
```

Comment: value will be out of scope since it is declared inside the using block.

Comment: @LeeO.: declare it on top of selectQuery variable, check my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Every exit point of a procedure must be covered if the procedure has a return value.

If you can't find a property, perhaps you consider that an error and you should raise one:

```
throw new Exception("Cannot find property");
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to handle the *exceptional* case where no property has been found.

If it's really not expected, then your use case is definitely a good candidate for an exception being thrown:

```
private string GetWMIProperty(string property)
{
    SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
    {
        ...
    }

    thrown new ArgumentException("no WMI property found for specified property name", "property");
}
```

If it's expected in some cases and it's OK, then just return a **default value** as you already did (such as `string.Empty`).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable outside of the "using" block to hold the mo[property] values generated within the foreach loop, you will be able to use a single return statement at the end of the method block as shown below.  It looks like you're expecting more than one string to be generated within the using statement, in which case you will want to make the "value" variable and the return type a list of string.

```
private List<string> GetWMIProperty(string property)
   {
       List<string> values = new List<string>();
       SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
       using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
       {
           foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
           {
               values.Add(mo[property].ToString());
           }
       }
       return values
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little subtle, but the problem is, when you put your return in a `foreach` loop you are effectively doing something like this:

```
if (myCollection.Count > 0) 
{
    return myCollection[0];
}
else
{
    // This path doesn't have a return value!!!
}
```

That's why VS is complaining. Since you are only returning the first value, perhaps it would be better to do:

```
 return searcher.Get().FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead of the foreach loop.